# About proof : limit & sigma

Tags: integration, limits

$f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ is differentiable. And    second derivative $f''(x)$ is     continuance.
$$\int ^{b}_{a}f\left( x\right) dx-\dfrac{b-a}{2}\left( f\left( a\right) +f\left( b\right) \right)=-\dfrac{1}{2}\int ^{b}_{a}f''\left( x\right) \left( x-a\right) \left( b-x\right) dx-①$$

In ①, when a constant $M$ holds $\left| f''\left( x\right) \right| <M $for any point $x$ in the interval $\left[ a,b\right]$
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }n\left[ \int _{a}^{b}f\left( x\right) dx-\dfrac{b-a}{n} \left\{\dfrac{f\left( a\right) +f\left( b\right) }{2}+\sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}f\left( a+\dfrac{\left( b-a\right) k}{n}\right) \right\} \right] =0$$
I want to show that this holds.

I expand a formula.

$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }n\int _{a}^{b}f\left( x\right) dx+\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{b-a}{n}\sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}f( a+\dfrac{\left( b-a\right) k}{n})+\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{\left( b-a\right) ( f\left( a\right) +f\left( b\right) )}{2n}$

I got stuck here. Please tell me how to prove from here.

Comment: I fin this question very confusing: the funcion $f$ and its second derivative $\;f''\;$ are continuous both, right? Now, is (1) given **or what**? and then you want to prove that limit you wrote there is zero...is this correct?

Comment: Yes.It is correct.

Comment: @langhtorn There is some information missing in your question. What is the domain of $f?$ Is $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ or $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}.$ I would suggest editing the question to include all the given information. Also, you have expanded the formula wrong. You didn't multiply $n$ with the second term (it's supposed to cancel out).

Answer (score 1):

Up to a change of variable we may assume $[a,b]=[0,1]$. If $f''(x)\in C^0([0,1])$ integration by parts ensures
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}f''(x)x(1-x)\,dx &=&\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)(2x-1)\,dx\\&=&\left[f(x)(2x-1)\right]_{0}^{1}-2\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the first formula
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx - \frac{b-a}{2}(f(b)-f(a))=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}f''(x)(x-a)(b-x)\,dx \tag{1}$$
is proved. By the mean value theorem for integrals
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f''(x)(x-a)(b-x)\,dx = f''(\xi)\int_{a}^{b}(x-a)(b-x)\,dx = \frac{1}{6}f''(\xi)(b-a)^3 \tag{2}$$
for some $\xi\in(a,b)$. If we consider a partition of $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal sub-intervals, by applying $(1)$ and $(2)$ to each one of these intervals we get that the difference between $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ and the approximation through the trapezoidal rule
$$ \frac{b-a}{n}\left[\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f\left(a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right)\right] \tag{3}$$
is bounded by
$$ \frac{1}{12}\underbrace{\max_{x\in[a,b]}\left|f''(x)\right|}_{M}\cdot n\cdot \frac{1}{n^3} = O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).\tag{4}$$